# Bootstrap: how to position two ng-repeat divs in a row while the one of the two will stay on the top

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project where a user stores product information and creates articles. On my home view i have two divs. The one on the left is a ng-repeat which retrieves the articles of the products. The one on the right is a ng-repeat also, which shows my product list.

My problem is when i GET my articles, the right one div, breaks the line and shows up on my last result of my article.

this is the position of the right div **i want**

[image: This is the position i want]

this is the position of the right div **i dont want**

[image: this is the position i dont want]

here is my home view:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <style>


            .col-md-4 {
                        float: right;


            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">




    <br/>




        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8" ng-repeat="article in articles" >


                    <div class="panel panel-white post panel-shadow">
                        <div class="post-heading">
                            <div class="pull-left meta">
                                <div class="title h5">
                                    <b>{{article.title}}</b>                
                                </div><br/>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> {{article.published}}</li>
                        <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> {{article._creatorname}}</li>
                        <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="remove(article._id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></li>
                        </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="post-description"> 
                            <p>{{article.body}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-footer">
                            <div class="input-group"> 
                               <input type="text" id="userComment" ng-model="comment" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Write your message here..." /> 
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">     
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="addComment(article._id, comment)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Add Comment</button>
                                        </span>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="comments-list">
                                <li class="comment" ng-repeat="comment in article.comments">                        
                                    <div class="comment-body">
                                      <div class="comment-heading">
                                            <h4 class="user">{{comment._commentorname}}</h4>
                                            <h5 class="time">{{comment.date}}</h5>  
                                            <div class="pull-right meta">
                                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeComment(article._id, comment._id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</button>
                                            </div>        


                                      </div>
                                        <p style="width: 350px;">{{comment.content}}</p>
                                    </div>                    
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">                          
                <section class="panel panel-default mail-categories">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <strong><span class="fa fa-th"></span> 
                                    Resources</strong>
                            </div>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                                    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="resource in resources">
                            {{resource.name}}, Model Number: {{resource.modelno}}
                            </li>
                                </ul>
                </section>

            </div>


        </div>


    </div>      


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Without a working demo that includes appropriate css is hard to help for something like this without being able to inspect elements/style in browser dev tools

Comment: ok ty for your comment! i found the problem!